# install_name_tool -change fails silently and ignores -headerpad_max_install_names flag

Tags: macos, gcc, dylib, otool, install-name-tool

I have a command-line executable that includes links to dylibs that — when distributed — will not be at the stated location returned by `otool -L`.

For instance, given a binary called `foo`:

```
$ otool -L foo
  /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.18.0)
  ...
```

In my installer, I have a post-installation script that tries to use `install_name_tool -change` to fix this, so that `foo` links to the dylib in its new location.

For instance:

```
$ sudo install_name_tool -change /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libstdc++.6.dylib /somewhere/else/more/sensible/libstdc++.6.dylib foo
```

But this change is ignored and fails silently. When I run `otool -L` again:

```
$ otool -L foo
  /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.18.0)
  ...
```

Nothing changed.

I am compiling fat binaries and tried adding the `-headerpad_max_install_names` compilation flag to the 32-bit Makefile. This did not fix the problem, in that `install_name_tool -change` still fails silently.

I read that `-headerpad_max_install_names` does nothing on 64-bit platforms, but I added it to the 64-bit Makefile anyway. Predictably, this did not fix the problem, either.

How do I fix my compilation procedure, so that I can ultimately change the path of the linked dylib with `install_name_tool`?

Comment: Something appears to be broken with 10.6 support and the build of `gcc` available through MacPorts. I can't get much support through the MacPorts folks, so I've dropped 10.6 support for now (e.g., compiling with the `-mmacosx-version-min=10.7` flag setting).

Comment: install_name_tool displays an error if there is not enought room for the new library path (at least on 10.9)